# Avergeifs comparing YYYY-MM-DD with Datetime?

Tags: excel, datetime

I'm trying to use an "Avergageifs"-formula to compare a list of YYYY-MM-DD values to a longer list of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM values (and I have other criteria, therefore, the "ifs"). I cannot figure out how to write the formula for excel to understand that "2017-01-01" is the same as "2017-01-01 12:23" for example. Suggestion? Googling this and trying different solutions, but it doesn't stick as none of the examples I find correspond to my issue.

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Table1[[Column1]];Table1[Column2];$F$16;Table1[ColumnWithYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format];A1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The time portion is a decimal so braket your date:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Table1[[Column1]];Table1[Column2];$F$16;Table1[ColumnWithYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format];">=" & A1;Table1[ColumnWithYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format];"<" & A1+1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would have never figured that one out myself (:

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.